# Why is the for loop ending very early?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Node js (I am running the server with nodemon) to upload an excel file, parse it and send each row to a Mongodb database, the length of the complete array of rows is 476 but it ends the loop at number 31 or 95 and never finishes all the rows. I want to get all the rows but I really dont understand why is not completing the loop.

Here is the console.log of the iterations:

[image]

Here is the Node js server file:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    var exceltojson;
    upload(req, res, function(err){
        if (err) {
            res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
            return;
        }
        if(!req.file){
            res.json({error_code:1, err_desc:"No file passed"});
            return;
        }

        if(req.file.originalname.split('.')[req.file.originalname.split('.').length-1] === 'xlsx'){
            exceltojson = xlsxtojson;
        } else {
            exceltojson = xlstojson;
        }
        try {
            exceltojson({
                input: req.file.path,
                output: "./outPutJSON/output.json",
                lowerCaseHeaders: true
            }, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    return res.json({error_code:1, err_desc:err, data: null});
                }
                res.json({datos:"Data was succesfully added "});

                fs.readFile("./outPutJSON/output.json", 'utf8', async (err, fileContents) => {
                    if (err) {
                      console.error(err);
                      return;
                    }
                    try {
                      let data = JSON.parse(fileContents);  // this variable has all the cases
                      console.log(data + 'the cases');
                      console.log(data.length + ' length of the cases')

                      for(let cantidad = 0; cantidad < data.length; cantidad++){    //here is the loop
                        var document = data[cantidad];
                        console.log(cantidad + ' - ' + data.length + ' - ' + document);
                        if(document.nombre === '' || document.cedula === '' || document.direccion === '') {
                            console.log('Could not save cases');
                        } else {
                            var mostrar = await increment();
                            document.caso = mostrar;
                            document.montoApoderado = data[cantidad]['monto apoderado'];
                            document.numeroCliente = data[cantidad]['no.cliente'];
                            document.numeroProducto = data[cantidad]['no.producto'];
                            let today = moment().format('YYYY M D');
                            document.fechaCreado = today;
                            var mod = new model(document);
                            await mod.save(document); 
                        }
                      }
                    } catch(err) {
                      console.error(err);
                    }
                  })

                });

                var fs = require('fs');
                try {
                    fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path)
                }catch(e){

                }
        } catch (e) {
            res.json({error_code:1, err_desc:"Corrupted excel file"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Run it with `node app.js` instead of `nodemon app.js`.

Comment: Problem solved, I ran the server with node app.js and all the rows where added. thank you str.

Comment: tldr you're changing files, and have nodemon configured to restart when changes are detected. It detects changes, and therefore restarts, in the middle of your loop.

Comment: To confirm, the issue was running with nodemon, not directly with node, which was monitoring the folder you writing files to?

Comment: Yes exactly, I was running the server with nodemon.

Comment: OK, please consider accepting the answer below which explains why so other users can find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you made be writing the modified files to a directory that is being included in nodemon to monitor for changes. This is triggering a restart. Double-check that and adding paths to ignore in your config file:

Example:

```
"ignore": ["*.test.js", "fixtures/*"],
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try debugging it at the points of failure(i.e start your loop at i=31. Also, it looks like a case of a timeout to me. You could also check if that is the case.